# How to write a function in android to match last char in a string?

Tags: android

I hope to write a function to return if a string match last char in a string?

For example,

s2 match last chars in a string s1, so the function return true
s3 match last chars in a string s1, so the function return true
s4 match last chars in a string s1, so the function return true
n1 don't match last chars in a string s1, so the function return false
n2 don't match last chars in a string s1, so the function return false
n3 don't match last chars in a string s1, so the function return false
n4 don't match last chars in a string s1, so the function return false

String s1="abcdefg"
String s2="fg"
String s3="efg"
String s4="defg"
String n1="gf"
String n2="ag"
String n3="feg"
String n4="fgg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `endsWith()`. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Simply compare:

```
if(s1.endsWith(s2)) {
  // s2 matches the last characters in s1
}
else {
  // s2 doesn't match the last characters in s1
}
```

> Returns: `true` if the character sequence represented by the argument
>   (s2) is a suffix of the character sequence represented by this object
>   (s1); `false` otherwise. Note that the result will be true if the
>   argument (s2) is the empty string or is equal to this object (s1)

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isLastCharEqual(String first, String second) {
    if (first == null || second == null || first.length() == 0 || second.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return first.contains(second) && (first.charAt(first.length() - 1) == second.charAt(second.length() - 1));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for poor english, I mean S2 is substring of S1 first. n2 don't match last chars in a string s1, so the function return false

Comment: @user828896 Check the edited answer, in that case just check if first contains second string.

Comment: Thanks! But I think your function can't correct result for s1 and n4